# Reactjs call backend API only one time when component loads first time

Tags: reactjs

I have a two react functional components:
a) ParentComponent
b) ChildComponent:

I am calling ChildComponent from ParrentComponent.
In my ChildComponent I am calling an API to get data (Let Say Filters common data), now everytime I call ChildComponent from parents my APIs in ChildComponent gets called.
However I just want these API calls only first time and then want to use the APIs response data for other rendors.

I have used useEffect, useCallback but seems I am not able to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling the API with useEffect, it's gonna be execute everytime you call the ChildComponent. Instead, if you only want to call the API just one time, move the API call to the ParentComponent and send the response to the ChildComponent using params.

You can also use Context, but I think that is not a must in this case.

Comment: Yeah I could move API Call in the ParentComponent and then pass the data to ChildComponent, but if I need to show the loader (spiner) in the ChildComponent (until I get the data from that parent API call), how can I do that?

Comment: Maybe you can uso another param like loading and handle it as a state on ParentComponent, this state could be a boolean. Then show the spiner in the ChildComponent if loading is true.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect(() => {}, [])` should run only on first render. If that doesn't work, you can always put your fetch in the parent component instead, and send down the data to the child component. In this way it will only load once.

Comment: Yeah that could be done, If I move API call to ParengeComponent then in this case I will be calling the API before child component and there is a possibility user don't click on that button whic require that ChildComponent open and in this case it will be no use of Calling backend API and it will not be used.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function to fetch Data and wrap it whit useCallback then call this function in UseEffect and add function to dependecies. It should run only in first render

useCallback will prevent infinite loop

Comment: I tried these steps but seems not working.
Here is my chiledComponent:

  const getInteractionTypes =  useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('/somepiCall');
  },[]);



  useEffect(()=>{
    getInteractionTypes();
  }, [getInteractionTypes]);